# converting an array of elements to single object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of either length 1 or 2 or 3.

```
$scope.array = [(P1:'FirstName', P2:'LastName'),(P1:'FirstName', P2:'LastName')]
```

I want to convert this array to single object with following properties (object property name taken from array value and property value is '').

```
var obj = { FirstName:'', LastName:''};
```

How i can achieve it?
Any idea?

Comment: Simply iterate over the array and the properties of each object and assign the values as property name to a new object. What specifically are you having problems with? Do you know how to iterate over arrays? Over objects? How to assign a property to an object?

Comment: i am missing algorithm here (pseudo) and nothing like array iteration or object property assignment. appreciated u can share then algo. thanks

Comment: Alright, here is the pseudo code: `for element in array { for propertyValue in element { newObject[propertyValue] = ''; } }`. Again, it's simply iterating over the array elements and object properties.

Comment: Fine, i got it working. thanks